# Pop from Stack of arrays in C - assigning NULL to a int *

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

Considering the following definition of a Stack of arrays:

```
typedef struct larray{
    int values[BSize];
    struct larray *prox;
}*LArrays;

typedef struct stack{
    int sp; //number of occupied positions in stack's top array
    LArrays s; //stack top
}Stack;
```

I wrote this pop function:

```
int pop(Stack *st, int *t){
    if (st->sp == 0) return -1;

    if (st->sp == 1){
        LArrays newTop = st->s->prox;
        free(st->s);
        st->s = NULL;
        st->s = newTop;
        st->sp = BSize;
        return 0;
    }

    LArrays l = st->s;
    int *remover = l->values + (--st->sp);  
    *t = *remover;
    *remover = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

It works. But when compiling, gcc produces this warning:

> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>
> ```
>      *remover = NULL;
> ```

**Is it wrong to assign NULL to a int *?**

### [Results after change to remover = NULL]

Main:

```
for (; i < 150; i++)
        push(stack,i);
    i = 0;

    printStack(stack);

    for (; i < 70; i++)
        pop(stack,&r);

    printStack(stack);
```

> with *remover = NULL (produces desired output!)

```
//stack after push

100|101|102|103|104|105|106|107|108|109|110|111|112|113|114|115|116|117|118|119|120|121|122|123|124|125|126|127|128|129|130|131|132|133|134|135|136|137|138|139|140|141|142|143|144|145|146|147|148|149|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|]

---------------------------------------------------------
0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99|]

//stack after pop
0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|]
```

> with remover = NULL (does not produce the desired output!)

```
//stack after push

100|101|102|103|104|105|106|107|108|109|110|111|112|113|114|115|116|117|118|119|120|121|122|123|124|125|126|127|128|129|130|131|132|133|134|135|136|137|138|139|140|141|142|143|144|145|146|147|148|149|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|]

---------------------------------------------------------
0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99|]


//stack after pop
0|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10|11|12|13|14|15|16|17|18|19|20|21|22|23|24|25|26|27|28|29|30|31|32|33|34|35|36|37|38|39|40|41|42|43|44|45|46|47|48|49|50|51|52|53|54|55|56|57|58|59|60|61|62|63|64|65|66|67|68|69|70|71|72|73|74|75|76|77|78|79|80|81|82|83|84|85|86|87|88|89|90|91|92|93|94|95|96|97|98|99|]
```

**Print funtions:**

```
void printArray(int *v, int N){
    int *p = v;
    int i = 0;
    for(; i < N; i++)
        printf("%d|",*p++);
    printf("]\n\n");
}

void printStack(Stack *stack){
    LArrays p = stack->s;
    printf("Free Space on Stack's head: %d\n",BSize - stack->sp);
    printf("\nStack:\n\n");
    while(p->prox != NULL){
        printArray(p->valores,BSize);
        printf("------------------------------------------------\n");
        p = p->prox;
    }printArray(p->values,BSize);
}
```

Comment: You're **not** assigning `NULL` to `int *`, you're assigning `NULL` to `int`, which is mostly wrong.

Comment: BTW what is the aim of assigning `NULL` to a local scoped variable just before the end of function?....

Comment: @LPs Probably a suggestion of some "good coding practice". And just interested, what harm it can cause? Any moderate compiler will anyway optimize out the instruction, right?

Comment: Well, sure ;). I was only wondering if OP is trying to achieve something that is not be clear in posted code

Comment: Just remove this `remover`-dereference-assignment, as its useless.

Comment: Voting to close this as a simple typo.

Comment: @Lundin IMHO, it's not a typo, it's a misconception that needs to be cleared. I agree, pretty basic concept, though.

Comment: @SouravGhosh In which case it should be closed as a dupe to any of the thousands of already existing questions with the same misconception.

Comment: You mind creating a [___MCVE___](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Referring your update: I do not see how the output matches the code shown.

Comment: @alk print functions added

Answer (score 1):

It's **not wrong** to assign `NULL` to an `int *`, but it's not always correct either to assign it to an `int`. It is implementation defined behavior.

To elaborate, `NULL` is

> `NULL`
>
> which expands to an implementation-defined null pointer constant; [...]

and then, quoting chapter §6.3.2.3/p6 (*emphasis mine*)

> Any pointer type may be converted to an integer type. Except as previously specified, **the
>   result is implementation-defined. If the result cannot be represented in the integer type,
>   the behavior is undefined.**

So, your compiler is warning you for good.

It looks like, here, you just have a misconception of how to use the pointer variable. You don;t need to go for dereference. You need to change

```
 *remover = NULL;
```

to

```
remover = NULL;   // assign NULL to the pointer variable, not to the value it points to.
```

to get rid of the warning.

Comment: ... and what good would that assignment do, since it is a local variable and never reused :d

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Nothing, but the issue in the code will re fixed. ;)

Comment: please consider the edit I just made. I understood what you said, but the first way (the warning one) produces the desired option and the second one don't.

Comment: Please see my comments under your question.

Answer (score 1):

You're not assigning NULL to an `int *`.  You're assigning it to an `int`.

`remover` is of type `int *`, while `*remover` dereferences that pointer and is of type `int`.

Change that line to the following:

```
remover = NULL;
```

Actually, you can remove that line entirely, since `remover` is not referenced after that point.

Comment: please consider the edit I just made. I understood what you said, but the first way (the warning one) produces the desired option and the second one don't.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `NULL` not to `int *`, but to an `int`. You do `*remover = NULL;`, and `remover` is `int *`, and `*remover` is int.

Answer (score 1):

That's not what the warning says. It says that `*remover = NULL` is assigning a pointer (`NULL`) to an integer (`*remover`) (see your declaration, it says "`*remover` is an `int`").

Would you want to assign `NULL` to the `int *` called `remover`, do this:

```
remover = NULL;
```

This is perfectly legal.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it wrong to assign NULL to a int *?

No, doing so is perctly valid.

However that's not what the compiler is complaing about.

Read the message carefully (what one should always do, BTW ;-):

> ```
> warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>  *remover = NULL;
> ```

Now let's take the warning apart:

> ```
> ... assignment makes integer ...
> ```

This translates to:  "*The code [tries] to assign to an integer ...*"

> ```
> ... from pointer ...
> ```

This translates to: "*... from a pointer (value) ...*"

Looking at the line in question:

```
 *remover = NULL;
```

we see that `*remover` is getting assigned and `NULL` is the value assigned.

Putting all this together we can conclude that the compiler is taking

```
*remover
```

to be an integer, and

```
NULL
```

to a be a pointer (value).

Adding up to this that "*the compiler never fails*", you should be able to understand the issue.

:-)

Comment: `NULL` is not a pointer **variable** And that is not what the message says. Do you mean "pointer **value**"?

Comment: please consider the edit I just made. I understood what you said, but the first way (the warning one) produces the desired option and the second one don't.

Comment: @Olaf: Correct, thank you; I missed to correct this. Did this now.

Comment: @JohnBauer: We do not know what `printStack()` does. But perhaps you just want: `*remover = 0;`

Comment: @alk printStack() posted. I was trying to make the removed element position NULL. But what do you think that makes more sense in stack's context?

Comment: @JohnBauer: An integer cannot be `NULL`, only pointers can. `NULL` is the null-pointer value. An `int`'s value, for example, can range from `INT_MIN` to `INT_MAX`, that's it. There are other `*_MIN`/`*_MAX` constants for the other integer types (see `limits.h`). You could, for example, use one of those limits to mark the entry on the stack as "not in use".

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning to a value pointed by remover . If you want to assign NULL to a pointer then use this .

remover = NULL;